# Guzzle not returning body resulting in $request->getBody() not providing the addFile() function

Tags: guzzle

I've included 'https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/releases/download/5.2.0/guzzle.phar' using `require 'guzzle.phar';`

I've then added

```
$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client();

$request = $client->createRequest("POST", <URL>);

$postBody = $request->getBody();

$postBody->addFile(new PostFile('file', fopen('@./images'.$location, 'r')));

$response = $client->send($request);

$body = $response->json();

return $body['id'];
```

But I get

```
Error: Call to a member function addFile() on null
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

To fully understand your error we must look at the source code for the [Request::__construct()](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Message/Request.php#L39), [AbstractMessage::getBody()](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Message/AbstractMessage.php#L31), and  [Request::handleOptions()](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Message/Request.php#L156) methods.

As you can see, if the request is instantiated without the 'body' option, it will be set to null.  So, when you call `$request->getBody()` you receive `NULL` instead of a `MessageInterface` instance.